# Polymer - Component Layout

Tags: css, polymer

I'm working on a Polymer app. In this app, I have three fields that I am trying to layout horizontally. I need them to be kind of spaced evenly.Essentially, I'm trying to create the following. Please note, the [] means an icon.

```
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| [] First Name              |        [] Last Name        |          [] Email          |
|    __________              |           _________        |             bill@gmail.com |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

The first column is left aligned. The middle column is centered (notice the label is left-aligned above the field). The right column content is right-aligned as a block (notice the label is not right-aligned over the field). In an attempt to implement this, I did the following:

```
<div class="horizontal flex layout">
  <div class="horizontal layout flex-3">
    <iron-icon icon="home" style="padding:18px 8px 0px 0px;"></iron-icon>
    <paper-input label="first name" value="{{ firstName }}"></paper-input>
  </div>

  <div style="width:18px;">&nbsp;</div>

  <div class="center-justified flex-6">
    <div class="horizontal layout">
      <iron-icon icon="schedule" style="padding:18px 8px 0px 0px;"></iron-icon>
      <paper-input label="last name" value="{{ lastName }}"></paper-input>                                  
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="width:18px;">&nbsp</div>

  <div class="flex-3">
    <div class="horizontal layout end-justified">
      <iron-icon icon="chart" style="padding:18px 8px 0px 0px;"></iron-icon>
      <paper-input label="email" value="{{ emailAddress }}"></paper-input>                                      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code above does not align the elements properly. The Email address field is not right aligned within the cell. In addition, the last name field does not grow even though there is plenty of space on both sides. It gets truncated. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr: Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fewss46p/2/) with a working example of what you're trying to do

Here's the relevant code in that fiddle:

```
<style is="custom-style">
.horizontal-layout{
   @apply(--layout-horizontal);
   @apply(--layout-center);
}
.flexchild {
  @apply(--layout-flex);
}
.flex2child {
  @apply(--layout-flex-2);
}
.noflex {
  @apply(--layout-flex-none);
}
.center-justified {
  @apply(--layout-center-justified);
}
</style>
<div class="horizontal-layout">
  <div class="horizontal-layout flexchild">
    <iron-icon icon="home" class="noflex"></iron-icon>
    <paper-input label="first name" value=""></paper-input>
  </div>

  <div class="horizontal-layout flex2child center-justified">
    <div class="horizontal-layout">
      <iron-icon icon="schedule" class="noflex"></iron-icon>
      <paper-input label="last name" value=""></paper-input>               
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="horizontal-layout flexchild">
    <div class="horizontal-layout">
      <iron-icon icon="add" class="noflex"></iron-icon>
      <paper-input label="email" value=""></paper-input>             
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's an explanation to what's going on in there:

First of all, I'm not using `iron-flex-layout` classes, I'm using the mixins, this is because the `/deep/` and `::shadow`combinators are being deprecated and, since `iron-flex-layout` classes use them, the Polymer team recommends not using them. ([Here's a blog post](https://blog.polymer-project.org/announcements/2015/12/01/deprecating-deep/) with more info)

For that reason, I created some css classes that apply those mixins:

- `.horizontal-layout` makes the elements inside display among a
  horizontal main axis(`--layout-horizontal`) and get centered in the
  vertical cross axis(`--layout-center`)
- `flexchild` and `flex2child` are there so that when elements with both of this classes are present in a flex container they shrink or grow so that `flexchild`'s always are half the size of `flex2child`s
- `noflex` prevents that same shrinking and growing (this is to prevent the icons from shrinking)
- `center-justified` centers the elements inside that container on their main axis

Note that I removed the divs you had with a fixed width as well as the other styles that involved positioning or sizing as those usually get in the way or are simply ignored by flexbox styles.

Knowing all that, you should be able to figure out how everything works in the fiddle. If you want to further customize the layout, there a really cool [guide on the Polymer Catalog](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/flex-layout)

I hope this helped.